# Comparing Values of Two arrays in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy, indexing

I have a large dataset trying to read with Pandas. I am trying to split the value of one of the column in two parts and check if there is any overlapping values between these sets. With the codes below the result is there are some value overlapping in array 'b' and array 'c'. I want to get those values specifically but don't know how? Can anybody point me in the right direction?

```
df = pd.read_csv('....csv')

df2 = df[df['Freq']>= 280]
a=df2['Ring'].values
b=df2['Ring'].drop_duplicates().values

df3 = df[df['Freq']<= 280]
df3['Ring'].values
c=df3['Ring'].drop_duplicates().values

if np.all(b) == np.all(c):
    print ("They are overlapping")
else:   
    print ("They are not overlapping")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example provided, you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np
np.intersect1d(b, c)
```

or you can also do something like:

```
cond = df['Freq'] >= 280
np.intersect1d(df[cond]['Ring'], df[~cond]['Ring'])
```

Comment: with the script you mentioned the result is there is no overlap between the values in array 'c' and array 'b' which is correct since i checked manually and there is no overlapping. But my question is that what is wrong with the "if condition" of my code?! since it is giving me "they are overlapping"

Comment: `np.all` tests if all elements in the array are true. So basically in your if statement, you are testing if both `b` and `c` contain non-zero elements.